# How to retrieve identity documents from Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I can successfully upload identification for Stripe connect accounts via the Stripe provided PHP library. In turn, this correctly verifies the user.

This is done in a snippet not unlike the following:

```
    $result = FileUpload::create([
        'purpose' => 'identity_document',
        'file' => fopen($filePath, 'r')
    ], [
        'stripe_account' => $accountStripeId
    ]);
```

From this request, I do get the following:

- A valid response, including the file ID (though as noted in the documentation, I receive null for the url because the type is `identity_document`)
- The connected account is marked as `verified` in the stripe system.

I should be content with this, as technically it's working, but it's hard to verify. I can't:

- See the uploaded ID in the dashboard (either as myself or when viewing the dashboard as the connected user)
- Can't retrieve the file upload via the returned File ID.

So.. Is there a way to retrieve the file upload via the upload ID for an `identity_document` type document?

**EDIT**

When trying to access a file via the Stripe provided PHP library, I receive the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "No such file upload: file_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "param": "id"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simple answer to this is that it is by design, and that once uploaded you cannot retrieve said documents

Comment: But then why stripe has given the api to retrieve the uploaded document ? I am also using the file retrieval api but getting the same error : No such file upload:file_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an uploaded file by making a `GET` request to the `uploads.stripe.com/v1/files` endpoint.

```
curl https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files/fil_15BZxW2eZvKYlo2CvQbrn9dc \
  -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2:
```

Currently, the official Stripe PHP SDK does not have this facility implemented.

You can do it like so:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files/' . $fileId,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: ' . $apiKey)
));
$file = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: The official PHP SDK  does have it actually, and both that and the direct curl response return "No such file upload: file_XXXXXXXXXX" as the error message. I should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: I just checked SDK source and couldn't find any implementation for file reteival from `uploads.stripe.com/v1/files`. Can you describe how did you try to grab the file with the help of SDK?

Comment: Sure - via: `$file = FileUpload::retrieve($uploadId);`

Comment: `FileUpload::retrieve()` does not return a file. It only returns a file upload obeject (JSON data). See https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_file_upload

Comment: That's fine - both the curl request and the FileUpload class return the 'No such file' message though. My assumption, although I can't find it documented, is that because of the file type being identity I can't retrieve

Comment: Since you are getting `invalid_request_error`, first see if the `FileUpload::create()` succeed. If it returns an object with a key `id` you can go to next step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99302/discussion-between-sasindu-mendis-and-chris).